# Mail php client sees my code

Tags: php, email, client

I made a php script to send an email in php by following this tutorial :

[Tutorial](http://www.siteduzero.com/informatique/tutoriels/e-mail-envoyer-un-e-mail-en-php-1)

It works but not always. Some users see my php code in their email.

For example :

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

 boundary="-----=2ba3f325bd1156f694ea4dbd4a2aee3f"

-------=2ba3f325bd1156f694ea4dbd4a2aee3f

Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Ceci est un test.

-------=2ba3f325bd1156f694ea4dbd4a2aee3f

Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-1"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

  <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe</title>
   </head>
   <body style="background-color:#f5f5f5;">
```

etc..

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: He/she means the whole multipart/alternative code instead of the plaintext or HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the mail function directly use a library like Swiftmailer http://swiftmailer.org/

Gives you more control over setting metadata, mime types, etc and avoid pitfalls.